# Should we be able to send users private messages?

Tags: support, messaging

This functionality might be here already but if so, I could not find it. If not, I feel that sometimes you want to ask people questions or defend a question. Without spamming the comments, would it be worth having the ability to send private messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can. Click on the chat link in the top menu of links. It's not private but you can interact with users real time. Otherwise comments are the only way.

Any other forms of private messaging has always been declined, and this would be no exception, especially with the chat officially available.

Comment: I see that if you click the down arrow next to stackexchange there is an inbox. When i click that it is blank. Forgive my ignorance but what is that used for? Also, I cannot find the chat link. Do you have to be a certain rep to enable it? Thanks

Comment: @Drewdin The chat link is in the top bar of SU, to the right of your name, and on the same bar as StackExchange inbox. The Inbox is used for replies using the comment system and chat messages.

Comment: Thanks, i dont have it here in meta but i do have it in SU, hats why i couldn't find it. Thanks for the info

Comment: @Drew It's only on Super User's main site. Meta doesn't link to chat.

Comment: You also need 20 rep to talk in chat: http://superuser.com/privileges/chat

Comment: Worse comes to worse, just create a new room.

Answer (score 1):

*Sometimes*, you can contact a user by checking their profile to see if they have contact info in their description, or a website that has contact info.

Comment: SU chat is stateful.

Comment: You don't have to be there at the same time and you can read over the transcript

Comment: Good point; that works too.